# I need to calculate $x^{50}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$x=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$, I need to calculate $x^{50}$

Could anyone tell me how to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: See [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: in particular, $x^{50} = x^{32}x^{16}x^2$, so you can do it with only 7 matrix multiplications.

Comment: Do the first few powers by hand.  There is a pattern that you should spot.

Comment: There is a pattern, just work out a few powers.

Comment: Is this not the Cayley Hamilton theorem? (Matrix of eigenvectors * matrix of eigenvalues * matrix of eigenvectors inverted = matrix, so Matrix^n is just matrix of eigenvalues ^n which only has entries along the diagonal?)

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes, diagonalisation is great for powers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Start by computing $X^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Since $X^2 = I + N$ where $N^2 = 0$, and what you ask for is $(X^2)^{25} = I^{25} + 25I^{24}N + (\ldots)N^2$, the answer may be found by inspection:

$$ X^{50} = I + 25N $$

Answer (score 47):

This is a very elementary approach based on finding the general form. If we do $x^2$, we find $$x^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix},~~x^4=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\2&1&0\\2&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ so I guess that we have $$x^{2k}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\k&1&0\\k&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ An inductive approach adimits this general form is valid for integers $k>0$.

Answer (score 28):

The graph with adjacency matrix $$x:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
is drawn below:

[image: Graph with adjacency matrix]

For $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}$, the element in cell $(i,j)$ in $x^{50}$ is the number of walks from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ of length $50$ in the above graph.

We can thus immediately deduce from the graph structure that $x^{50}$ has the form $$x^{50}:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\?&1&0\\?&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ since $50$ is even.

With a bit of thought, we can surmise that there are $25$ walks from vertex $2$ to vertex $1$ of length $50$ (we can land at vertex $1$ after step $1,3,\ldots,49$, after which the walk is determined).  Similarly, there are $25$ walks from vertex $3$ to vertex $1$ of length $50$.

Hence $$x^{50}:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\25&1&0\\25&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: What is the rationale behind representing a matrix multiplication problem as a graph traversal problem? What is the intuition behind that and how did you get it?

Comment: Great answer! For me a completely new idea how to approach such a problem.

Comment: @Ali You might be interested in learning about Markov chains: vectors are commonly used to represent probability states, and transitioning from one state from another involves multiplying by a matrix, in a similar (though not identical) way as how is done here.

Answer (score 24):

The Jordan Decomposition yields
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}
$$
Block matrices are easier to raise to a power:
$$
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]^{50}
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]^{50}
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}\\[6pt]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 50 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]^{-1}\\[6pt]
&=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 25 & 1 & 0 \\
 25 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 16):

Evaluate the first few powers and guess
$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^{2n}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\n&1&0\\n&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, proof by induction. Then $x^{50}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\25&1&0\\25&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 8):

Try to prove by induction that:
$$
A^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ \left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil&n+1\bmod{2}&n\bmod{2}\\\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor&n\bmod{2}&n+1\bmod2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 7):

It helps if you start off by calculating a few of the powers by hand, e.g. the first four. We have
$$M^2 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$
$$M^3 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$
$$M^4 = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$
My eye picks out a pattern in $M^2$ and $M^4$. Can you prove by induction that
$$M^{2n} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ n & 1 & 0 \\ n & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$
Check the case for when $n=1$, then *assume* that it works for $n=k$, and show that this implies it also holds for $n=k+1$. You should be able to see the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to diagonalize the matrix. Say we could write $X=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal. Then computation would be easy since $X^{50}=PD^{50}P^{-1}$.

Comment: The matrix isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: The substitute for diagonalization is the Jordan normal form.  Then the 50th power is easy to compute.

Comment: stupid question: why isn't it diagonalizable? The det = -1, which means it should have 3 unique eigenvalues/vectors, right?

Comment: @user60462 For a matrix $A$, $\det A \neq 0$ means it is invertible but is not directly related to diagonalization (there are diagonalizable singular matrices, such as any symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, and non-diagonalizable invertible matrices such as this one). A $n\times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. In this case, the eigenvalue $1$ has a multiplicity 2 but the corresponding eigenspace is only 1 dimensional therefore $A$ is not diagonalizable.